# wpf scale to textBox,textBox can not display cursor when i click textBox

Tags: wpf

Zoom(ScaleTransform) TextBox, then mouse to click on the TextBox, and some can display the cursor, and some can not display the cursor,How to solution the problem. i hope that can show cursor after scale TextBox.

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="200"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Padding="0" Width="100"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="300"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Padding="0" Width="100" ></TextBox >
        <TextBox Padding="0" Width="100"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.35" ScaleY="0.65"></ScaleTransform>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
</Grid>
```